# passing dependencies of dependencies using manual constructor injection in python

Tags: python, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, manual

## My Situation

I'm currently writing on a project in python which I want to use to learn a bit more about software architecture. I've read a few texts and watched a couple of talks about dependency injection and learned to love how clear constructor injection shows the dependencies of an object.
However, I'm kind of struggling how to get a dependency passed to an object. I decided NOT to use a DI framework since:

1. I don't have enough knowledge of DI to specify my requirements and thus cannot choose a framework.
2. I want to keep the code free of more "magical" stuff since I have the feeling that introducing a seldom used framework drastically decreases readability. (More code to read of which only a small part is used).

Thus, I'm using custom factory functions to create objects and explicitly pass their dependencies:

```
    # Business and Data Objects
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def do_stuff(self):
        print(self.bar)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self,prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prefix)+"Hello"
    
# Wiring up dependencies
def create_bar():
    return Bar("Bar says: ")

def create_foo():
    return Foo(create_bar())

# Starting the application
f = create_foo()
f.do_stuff()
```

Alternatively, if `Foo` has to create a number of `Bar`s itself, it gets the creator function passed through its constructor:

```
# Business and Data Objects
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,create_bar):
        self.create_bar = create_bar
    def do_stuff(self,times):
        for _ in range(times):
            bar = self.create_bar()
            print(bar)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self,greeting):
        self.greeting = greeting
    def __str__(self):
        return self.greeting
    
# Wiring up dependencies
def create_bar():
    return Bar("Hello World")

def create_foo():
    return Foo(create_bar)

# Starting the application
f = create_foo()
f.do_stuff(3)
```

While I'd love to hear improvement suggestions on the code, this is not really the point of this post. However, I feel that this introduction is required to understand

## My Question

While the above looks rather clear, readable and understandable to me, I run into a problem when the prefix dependency of `Bar` is required to be identical in the context of each `Foo` object and thus is coupled to the `Foo` object lifetime. As an example consider a prefix which implements a counter (See code examples below for implementation details).
I have two Ideas how to realize this, however, none of them seems perfect to me:

### 1) Pass Prefix through Foo

The first idea is to add a constructor parameter to `Foo` and make it store the prefix in each `Foo` instance.

The obvious drawback is, that it mixes up the responsibilities of `Foo`. It controls the business logic AND provides one of the dependencies to `Bar`. Once `Bar` does not require the dependency any more, `Foo` has to be modified. Seems like a no-go for me. Since I don't really think this should be a solution, I did not post the code here, but provided it [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DMWM3pSD) for the very interested reader ;)

### 2) Use Functions with State

Instead of placing the `Prefix` object inside `Foo` this approach is trying to encapsulate it inside the `create_foo` function. By creating one `Prefix` for each `Foo` object and referencing it in a nameless function using `lambda`, I keep the details (a.k.a there-is-a-prefix-object) away from `Foo` and inside my wiring-logic. Of course a named function would work, too (but lambda is shorter).

```
# Business and Data Objects
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,create_bar):
        self.create_bar = create_bar
    def do_stuff(self,times):
        for _ in range(times):
            bar = self.create_bar()
            print(bar)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self,prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prefix)+"Hello"
        
class Prefix:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.count = 0
    def __str__(self):
        self.count +=1
        return self.name+" "+str(self.count)+": "
    
# Wiring up dependencies
def create_bar(prefix):
    return Bar(prefix)


def create_prefix(name):
    return Prefix(name)


def create_foo(name):
    prefix = create_prefix(name)
    return Foo(lambda : create_bar(prefix))

# Starting the application
f1 = create_foo("foo1")
f2 = create_foo("foo2")
f1.do_stuff(3)
f2.do_stuff(2)
f1.do_stuff(2)
```

This approach seems much more useful to me. However, I'm not sure about common practices and thus fear that having state inside functions is not really recommended. Coming from a java/C++ background, I'd expect a function to be dependent on its parameters, its class members (if it's a method) or some global state. Thus, a parameterless function that does not use global state would have to return exactly the same value every time it is called. This is not the case here. Once the returned object is modified (which means that `counter` in `prefix` has been increased), the function returns an object which has a different state than it had when beeing returned the first time.
Is this assumption just caused by my restricted experience in python and do I have to change my mindset, i.e. don't think of functions but of *something* callable? Or is supplying functions with state an unintended misuse of lambda?

### 3) Using a Callable Class

To overcome my doubts on stateful functions I could use callable classes where the `create_foo` function of approach 2 would be replaced by this:

```
class BarCreator:
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __call__(self):
        return create_bar(self.prefix)
     
def create_foo(name):
    return Foo(BarCreator(create_prefix(name)))
```

While this seems a usable solution for me, it is sooo much more verbose.

### Summary

I'm not absolutely sure how to handle the situation. Although I prefer number 2 I still have my doubts. Furthermore, I'm still hope that anyone comes up with a more elegant way.

Please comment, if there is anything you think is too vague or can be possibly misunderstood. I will improve the question as far as my abilities allow me to do :)
All examples should run under python2.7 and python3 - if you experience any problems, please report them in the comments and I'll try to fix my code.

Comment: Unless `create_prefix()` has side effects, your `create_foo()` function in option 2 is already side-effect free. What is the observable side effect here? You should delay the creation of foo by evaluating it inside the callable, but otherwise it is fine.

Comment: I think you are right that the functions I use are side-effect free. The fact I was referring to is that the result of the `create_bar` parameter is neither dependent on a parameter nor on global state, but can be modified by modifying its return value. I'll rephrase the corresponding section of my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject a callable object but don't want it to have a complex setup -- if, as in your example, it's really just binding to a single input value -- you could try using [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) to provide a function <> value pair:

```
def factory_function(arg):
    #processing here
    return configurted_object_base_on_arg

class Consumer(object):
   def __init__(self, injection):
      self._injected = injection

   def use_injected_value():
      print self._injected()

injectable = functools.partial(factory_function, 'this is the configuration argument')
example = Consumer(injectable)
example.use_injected_value() # should return the result of your factory function and argument
```

As an aside, if you're creating a dependency injection setup like your option 3, you probably want to put the knwledge about how to do the configuration into a factory class rather than doing it inline as you're doing here.  That way you can swap out factories if you want to choose between strategies.  It's not functionally very different (unless the creation is more complex than this example and involves persistent state) but it's more flexible down  the road if the code looks like

```
factory = FooBarFactory()
bar1 = factory.create_bar()
alt_factory = FooBlahFactory(extra_info)
bar2 = alt_factory.create_bar()
```

Comment: The partial function does look really tasty. Thanks for giving me that hint! It seems to combine the positive aspects of the callable class (it can be expected to have a state) and the lambda (only line of code for `create_foo`). See [pastebin] (http://pastebin.com/r8QuqPuc) for the complete example.

Comment: However, I don't really get the point of the second half of your comment. Are you suggesting something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hnMGxU3L)? If yes, I'm not yet seeing the improvement. Could you please clarify the advantages?

Comment: My main point was that using factory classes (rather than factory functions) can be useful in more complex cases.  The factory class can encapsulate all of the knowledge about how to configure the instances -- whenever you have to coordinate complex classes (say, business objects with special rules) it's nice to have that knowledege localized in one place. Plus, you can swap out factory claaaes at a higher level: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: To me it seems that the abstract factory is nothing but using the behavioral _strategy_ pattern as a creational pattern. I want to do something (create an object with a specific interface) but want to leave it to the strategy (the implementation of the abstract factory) to define how I do this (i.e. which parameters to pass, how to create the object and which class it should instantiate). Since functions are first class citizens in Python, there is (IMHO) no need for a reimplementation of the factory/strategy pattern. If you disagree, I'd love to see your point made clear by an example.

Comment: in the python universe it is mostly about preserving future flexibility -if some future implementation needs to be stateful you don't have to do major reworking. If you don't think that will ver be the case, it's more or less a wash. You can get a lot of the same benefits in python by just using duck-typing -- any class cam be your factory if it has a "create_bar" method so the whole strongly typed aspect of the abstract factory pattern isn't needed.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying and I absolutely agree to the point that some (possibly) stateful thing should be passed and handle the dependency. However, I think I have not yet formulated my point such that it is understandable enough. Let me try to do it short and clearly: Why is using a factory object that has a `create _bar` method superior to either my option 3 or the `functools.partial` approach you suggested? Any of these can hold state, create complex dependency trees. I don't see any situation at all, which factories (with `create_...`) methods could handle better.

Comment: I think the big variable is expectation of future complexity. If you're pretty sure the problem domain is locked down then partial is a simple way to go -- if this is inside something larger and has a very delimited responsibility for example.  OTOH if this is close to the public face of something - especially an API for other people to build on -- it is nice to provide a structure that makes it easier to organize the creation process.